# BTRFS RAID5/6 Alternative?

Tags: linux, btrfs

I have an embed ARM Linux device with 2 flash storage (each 16GB). RAM is 256 MB. It will be in a radiation environment. The probability of each flash storage failing is negligible compared to random bit corruption. I would need many parity blocks. Since [RAID5/6](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID56) is unstable. What other options can I use to protect data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the Btrfs built in Raid that currently has problems. That doesn't mean you cannot use a "normal" mdadm RAID-1 over the two devices (or equal size partitions thereof) and put Btrfs on top of that.

Of course Btrfs' built-in RAID (assuming it gets it bugs straightened out), has some advantages when doing a sync from one device to another (because Btrfs knows what part of a partition is being used and doesn't sync what is not used, whereas `mdadm` has no clue about usage and syncs the whole partition). For normal operations (read/writes) this advantage will be significantly less.

Whether RAID-1 is enough in your case of radiation is a different issue.